# Flutter get User's Country without Manual Permission

Tags: android, flutter, geolocation, flutter-dependencies, google-location-services

I have a Blog App where I write Bussiness Content for Global as well as some country-specific content. Like Special posts for India, Indonesia, etc.

That's why I need a way to find from which country the user is to provide specific content.

> But, I don't want to use the GeoLocator Plugin because It will ask the
> User for location. I only want the user's country, not the specific
> location but the permission dialog didn't specify that which can make
> the user anxious about why this app needs Location Permission. That's
> why I want a way to get user's Country without an implicit permission
> dialog asking for their location.

I have tried the following ways but none of them gave the exact country name.

```
import 'dart:io' show Platform;

String localeName = Platform.localeName;

// this returns language device is using which mostly comes us en_US so this is of no use


Locale myLocale = Localizations.localeOf(context);
// This returned the US as the country despite the App being opened and used in India.
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, I finally found an easy and simple way to get users' country.

http://ip-api.com/json

This link returns the Users' location in a JSON format. So All one has to do now, is to make a Get request to the above link/API and decode the JSON to Map.

For that First Install [HTTP](https://pub.dev/packages/http/install) Package:

Pubspec.yaml:

```
dependencies:
  http:
```

Code:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

Response data = await http.get('http://ip-api.com/json');
Map data = jsonDecode(data.body);
String country = data['country'];
```

EDIT:
As mentioned by good people,

```
Free Version Limit is 45 HTTP requests per second from an IP address.
```

Comment: yes it's working that way but you have just 45 req/s for the free version

Comment: @YasserBenmman 45 req/s for the free version for single IP.

Comment: Nice solution. Btw limit is  "45 HTTP requests per minute from an IP address."

Answer (score 2):

Locale gives you the language that the device user has set. It does not necessarily indicate their country of birth. It definitely does not tell you their country of residence. It may be that in many cases the person IS in the country of the language code but that is not guaranteed. The only way to know where they are is by location.

**Update**
Regarding your comment. If you mean where to get the country name based on the language code you get from the device locale, then have a look at this post. I haven't tried it myself but it seems promising. https://dev.to/thealphamerc/get-search-filter-countries-data-using-countryprovider-flutter-plugin-1epc

Comment: So, How can I get the user's country name?

Comment: Did this answer help you?

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
import 'dart:io' show Platform;

String localeName = Platform.localeName
```

or try this

please use package [devicelocale](https://pub.dev/packages/devicelocale)
I have tested with real device, it works fine

code snippet

```
String locale = await Devicelocale.currentLocale;
```

Comment: Have you read the question? I added the same code and told the problem with it.